# The concept/physical meaning/interpretations behind the Bessel's inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, inequality, geometric-inequalities

> If $\{\boldsymbol{\varphi}_1, \boldsymbol{\varphi}_2, ... \}$ is an orthonormal system in
>   $\mathcal{H}$, then the **Bessel's inequality** is:
>
> $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\langle \mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\varphi}_j \rangle|^2 \leq \lVert
>  \mathbf{x} \rVert^2 \quad \text{for every } \mathbf{x}\in \mathcal{H}.$$

My question is:

- What is the **meaning/concept** of this inequality?
- Is there any geometric or physical interpretations about that?

*Any comments or answers are appreciated.*

Comment: The idea is that, if you had a full basis, you would expect $x=\sum_j \langle x,\varphi_j\rangle\varphi_j$, which would then lead to $\|x\|^2=\sum_j |\langle x,\varphi_j\rangle|^2$. If the system is orthonormal, but not necessarily a full basis, then $\sum_j |\langle x,\varphi_j\rangle|^2 \le \|x\|^2$, because you might be missing components in the sum $\sum_j \langle x,\varphi_j\rangle \varphi_j$ needed to have a full expansion of $x$.

Comment: Thanks @TrialAndError. Could you please explain about the orthonormal basis and full basis in $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: In my comment replace "full basis" in the first sentence with "full orthonormal basis".

Comment: It can be a orthonormal basis of a subspace rather than the full space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like the Pythagorean theorem, but we might not have enough vectors in our orthonormal system to represent $x$ exactly.  If $x \in \mathbb R^3$ and we have an orthonormal set of vectors $\{\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3\} \subset \mathbb R^3$, then we can express $x$ as a linear combination $x  = \sum_{j=1}^3 \langle x,\phi_j\rangle \phi_j$. The Pythagorean theorem then tells us that $\|x\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^3 | \langle x,\phi_j\rangle |^2$. If we had only two vectors in our orthonormal set, we might not be able to represent $x$ exactly, and we would get an inequality rather than an equality.

Answer (score 2):

A **basis** for a vector space is a set of vectors which you can construct unique linear combinations of any vector in that space:

$$\text{if } {\bf u} \in V = \{{\bf v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n}\}$$
$$\text{then there exist unique } c_k \text{ so that } {\bf u} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k{\bf v}_k$$

A basis can span a **subspace** of a larger vector space, if there exist vectors in the larger vector space which can not be represented as such a combination.

The inequality then happens if the basis is for a subspace which the vector we sum scalar products over does not lie in the subspace, but has components outside of it. Those components will then be kind of *"invisible"* to the basis.